# Are called methods in a task is also in the task?

Tags: vb.net

So this is bothering me for a while and I don't know how to test it. Example,

```
   Sub Main()
    Dim task As New Task(Sub()
        Method1()
    )
    task.Start()
    End Sub

    Sub Method1()
        Method2()
    End Sub

    Sub Method2()
        'Am I also inside the task?
    End Sub
```

Is `Method2()` also in the `Task`?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be - what is making you doubt that?

Comment: @JamesThorpe Will a `System.Timers` also in the `Task`?

Comment: The creation of it will be, but usually anything done on the `Elapsed` event, like the `Task`, will be done on a thread pool thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are inside the Method two task. Think about things in procedural manner. When method one is called, you are in method one, which is where method 2 is being called, which is when you enter method 2. After everything is executed in Method 2, then it exits Method 2, and to the code, exits Method 1, and then back to Sub Main.